# How Can I Combine DateTime Value and Time Value Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a datetime value and time value which is string:

```
date:Date = new Date("2018-01-29");
time:string = "09:00:00";
```

I want to get a datetime value when date and time combined which is like:

```
Mon Jan 29 2018 09:00:00 GMT+0300 (GMT+03:00)
```

How can I do this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one simple way to do this:

```
const date: Date = new Date("2018-01-29");
const time: string = "09:00:00";
const newDate: Date = new Date(date.toDateString() + ' ' + time);

console.log(newDate);
```

**Demo in JS**:

```js
const date = new Date("2018-01-29");
const time = "09:00:00";
const newDate = new Date(date.toDateString() + ' ' + time);

console.log(newDate);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use **.replace()**

```js
const date = new Date("2018-01-29");
const time:string = " 09:00:00";
const newDate = JSON.stringify(date).replace('00:00:00', time);

console.log(newDate);
```